# Subclass a Python class with predefined parameters in one liner

Tags: python, class, subclassing

Given a simple class:

```py
class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self, param_a, param_b):
        
        self.param_a = param_a
        self.param_b = param_b

    def my_method(self, param_c):
        return some_fun(self.param_a, self.param_b)
```

Now I want to create an instance of this class with just `param_b` being set.
Namely something like:

```py
class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    def __init__(self, param_a):
        
        super().__init__(param_a, something)
```

Now I want: `my_obj_c = MyClassB(some_val)`.

The question, is there a way to get `my_obj_c` in one liner without explicitly building `MyClassB`?

#### Motivation

The reason I need this is actually this class is used by a different procedure which supports calling the class with a single input.
What I want is to try it (like grid search) which many different values of `param_b`. This is why setting a default value won't do it.

Comment: So param_a is optional?

Comment: @Unmitigated, no, I just missed it. Fixing it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What do you mean by "without explicitly building MyClassB"?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `get my_obj_c`. In your code `my_obj_c` is an instance of `MyClassB` -- that's it's type. Is that what you want, or are you really trying to make a `MyClassA` without specifying `param_b`?

Comment: You could make the default arguments of `A` optional. This would however maintain the `type` of `MyClassA` and not `MyClassB`

Comment: I will try to explain the logic.

Comment: @Mark, I would like to create instances of `MyClassA` which are not initialized by their `param_a` but only by their `param_b`. I edited the question with motivation. Could you tell me if it makes things clearer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand, what is the *problem* exactly? You seem to have found a solution.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I didn't found a solution. The solution now means I need to create a sub class for each `param_b` value. This is not feasible.

Comment: You need to supply *some* value for `param_a`. Otherwise, the best you can do is define some callable (another function or a `functools.partial` instance, for example) that *will* create an instance of `MyClassA` when finally given that value.

Comment: @chepner, Yep, I am just looking for an elegant simple way to do so.

Comment: `partial(MyClassA, param_b=bvalue)(avalue)`, but that's worse than `MyClassA(avalue, bvalue)` unless you plan on using a single instance `partial(MyClassA param_b=bvalue)` multiple times.

Comment: @chepner, Indeed. This follows the answer of Mark. I +1 it. If no other idea comes along I will mark it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make a partial of the class constructor with the second argument pre-set.

```
import functools 

class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self, param_a, param_b):        
        self.param_a = param_a
        self.param_b = param_b

    def my_method(self):
        return f"{self.param_a} {self.param_b}"

Paramterized = functools.partial(MyClassA, param_b="world")

my_instance = Paramterized("hello")
# <__main__.MyClassA at 0x112816e00> 
my_instance.my_method()
#'hello world'

my_instance2 = Paramterized("goodbye cruel")
my_instance2.my_method()
# 'goodbye cruel world'
```

Comment: This seems to be like I wanted. Is there a way to make it in a single step? Namely create the `my_instance...` in a single line?

Comment: I think this is where everyone is confused about what you are trying to do. `partial(MyClassA, param_b="world")("hello")` would work, but is clearly worse than just writing `MyClassA("hello", "world")`. Unless you plan on using `Parameterized` somewhere other than where you defined it, there's no need to define it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about

```
class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self, param_a, param_b=SomeValue):
...
```

this way you can create instance like this:

```
obj1 = MyClassA(param_a, param_b)
obj2 = MyClassA(param_a)
```

In the second instance the param_b will be someValue

Comment: The issue is I need to have this parameterized with many different values. So a default value won't solve it.